# Django sites framework and authentication

Tags: python, django

I want to build a web application using Django. Basically a CRM for specific business type. Lets say it's for Gyms for this explanation. I will have multiple customers. The customers will each get their own 3rd level domain name. Like golds.gym.com and 24hrfitness.gym.com. Each customer will have their own customers that will use the site as well. I want to allow overlapping usernames across sites, but unique to each site. I would also like to use the built in admin pages, but I will need to be sure that the admin pages are site specific. 
My question is more or less, "Is this possible". But I think what I really want to know is "Is this possible using something built in or something someone else has out there for Django?"
I have looked at the sites framework documentation and that seems to be what I need, however I have not found any documentation on how to make the admin and the users site specific.

Comment: you cant make domains through your website but you can create something like this */user/<username>/page* if you are interested tell me in the comments so i can answer  i am here to help you : )

Comment: "I want to allow overlapping usernames across sites, but unique to each site." - what?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, regarding your usernames: You can create your own `User` class based on Django's `AbstractBaseUser`, where you can make the email the primary unique authentication key and remove the requirement for unique usernames (adding a requirement for unique combination of site/username).

Comment: my take on this: why not use the standard django user model and make username a combination of site + username (e.g. siteb.myname). So users are saved in the db with the site as part of the username. In your `User` model you define a method to only display the part after the `.`. And override the authentication methods to prepend the site name to the username the user inserts in the login form.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do it with the sites framework, but it does take a significant amount of bootstrapping. This also goes under the assumption that you will use a different hostname for each site, as this is how the sites framework works.

When you use the sites framework, there is [middleware available that automatically populates the ID of the site on the request object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/#site-middleware).

If you want the end users to be able to use the admin section and see ONLY the objects on their account, you will need to have an `account` foreign key for every model.

You could then do something like overriding `get_queryset` in your views to automatically exclude any objects not belonging to the account.

Of course, you would also need a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) so that you can link users to sites.

If you are using postgres you could consider checking out [Django Tenant Schemas](http://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which accomplishes multi-tenancy using native postgres schemas.